# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRest/springPolicyService/policies/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringRest'

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

**Web.xml**

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
  <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>SpringRest</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Spring context**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd" >

<mvc:annotation-driven/>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.mypackage"/>
</beans>
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/springPolicyService")
public class SpringRestController {

    @Autowired(required=true)
    PolicyService policyService;

    @RequestMapping(name="/policies/{id}", method=RequestMethod.GET, headers="Accept=application/json")
    public List getPolicies(@PathVariable("id") int id){
        List<Policy> list= policyService.getPolicies(id);

        return list;
    }
}
```

But as soon as i give this URL:
**http://localhost:8080/SpringRest/springPolicyService/policies/1**

I get this : 
***Jun 26, 2017 3:57:53 AM org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringRest/springPolicyService/policies/1] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringRest'***

Comment: Remove the `/SpringRest` part of the URL (assuming that your app isn't deployed under `/SpringRest` but as root under `/`.

Comment: I tried and same problem

Comment: When i removed the pathvariable id and execute with :                                            http://localhost:8080/SpringRest/springPolicyService/policies    , i was able to get json output. Problem occurs when i try with pathvariable